# Mongodb make $text search work with an empty string as the single clause of an $or

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

The title of the question summarises my current approach in trying to do query that tries to achieve the following:

"Find all documents that match the text search criteria OR don't AND fulfil a bunch of other properties"

My query is below:

```
var query = {
            $or: [
                { $text: { $search: searchText } },
            ],
            $and: [
                {createdon: { $gte: start_date, $lt: end_date} },
                {author: req.user._id}
            ]

        };
```

If an empty string is sent by the user the query doesn't return any results although there are documents in the collection that fit the criteria sent in the request by the user inside the AND clause.

So basically I'm scratching my head as to how to get the $text search of MongoDB to work with an empty string.

I know I could simply text before creating the query, something like so:

```
  var query;
  if (!searchText.length) {
     //We know there's no search text, so just use the conditions in the AND clause
     query = {
         createdon: { $gte: start_date, $lt: end_date},
         author: req.user._id
     };
```

Just wondering If i can get this desired functionality without having to create the query object inside the control flow of a conditional.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't index spaces as part of full text

Comment: @Saleem I know that after looking at the docs, i'm just wondering if i'm doing something incorrect with the syntax of the $or condition or something along those lines.. Would you say the conditional declaration of the query is the way to go?

Comment: Your second approach is best way to go. it saves MongoDB from working hard for nothing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers:

I can't seem to work around this issue, so for now to get this to work i've gone with the conditional declaration of the query and that is working just fine.

```
  //Get the search text from the request     
  var searchText = req.body.searchText || "";

  var query = {
        event_date: { $gte: start_date, $lt: end_date},
        author: req.user.id
  };

  //Check if there is any search text before applying the $text query
  if (searchText.length) {

     query["$text"] = { $search: searchText }
  }
```

This now just ignores the text search if nothing was sent.

This is the answer until someone answers!

Comment: Thanks, this definitely is a great workaround. But since this was years ago, have you found another approach on this one or does mongo natively support something that does the same?